Unknown Error using react-photo-sphere-viewer from MarkersPlugin
I am programming a 360 viewer and I need to implement markers on it. I have problems since I am getting this error.
enter image description here
I have installer react-photo-sphere-viewer and @photo-sphere-viewer/core and I am still getting the error. I don't know what to do.
I am  implementing the Markers like this:
import { ReactPhotoSphereViewer, MarkersPlugin } from 'react-photo-sphere-viewer';

const plugins = [[ MarkersPlugin, { markers: [] } ]];

<ReactPhotoSphereViewer
            src={image}
            height='100vh'
            width="100%"
            plugins={plugins}
          >
          </ReactPhotoSphereViewer>

Any help will be amazing.
I tried installing react-photo-sphere-viewer and photo-sphere-viewer in NPM and still getting the error

I solved the error by implementing specific vertions of the npm libraries. Here are the versions:
@photo-sphere-viewer/core: ^5.7.1
photo-sphere-viewer: ^4.8.1
react-photo-sphere-viewer: ^4.2.1-psv5.6.0

I added these into the package.json and then npm install and problem solved.
